Does di(n-propyl)ether support Grignard reactions?
It is known that diethyl and dibutyl ethers are good solvents for Grignards, it has been also found that diisopropyl ether does not work. I have never seen dipropyl being discussed.
Edit: For clarity, ISOpropyl does not work very well, I want to know whether n-propyl would work.

It probably would work s a solvent, but di-isopropyl ether is more reactive than $n$- alkyl ethers to peroxide formation, which is an explosion hazard. Also when not exploding the peroxide function may also react with the Grignard reagent.

Wait, di(n-propyl)ether or di-isopropyl? It pretty much impossible that the linear isomer "does not work".

Not discussed in the literature probably because it is more expensive than diethyl ether and offers no significant advantages over that or di-n-butyl ether. I don't see why it would not work though.

A study was conducted in 1931 on this very subject. The full text was not available in Chemical Abstracts but the names of the authors, institution, and abstract were provided. (https://scifinder-n.cas.org/search/all/6668add88eab8e3392cf2506). The results are variable. Attempts to employ alkyl iodides gave poor results while alkyl bromides fared better.

Diisopropyl ether as a solvent in the Grignard reaction
By: Rathmann, F. H.; Leighty, J. A.
Transactions of the Illinois State Academy of Science (1931), 24, 312-5 |


On account of its cheapness and low volatility, (iso-Pr)2O would seem a desirable substitute for Et2O in the preparation of Grignard reagents. However, it was found less satisfactory in the following cases: MeI and Mg failed to react in (iso-Pr)2O in the presence of an I2 crystal. EtI and Mg reacted well at first, but the Mg was soon coated with a white solid. The yield was 22.5% against 86% in Et2O. MgEtBr was prepared in Et2O, (iso-Pr)2O and Bu2O media, giving yields of 75-88, 67.5 and 74-5%, resp. The reaction of iso-AmI on Mg in (iso-Pr)2O was stopped by a coating on the metal. PhBr and Mg in (iso-Pr)2O in the presence of an I2 crystal gave a yield of only 34%, although stirred mechanically under a reflux condenser for 3 hrs. Yields of Me2EtCOH and EtPhCHOH in (iso-Pr)2O were less than half the yields in Et2O.



Paper I have read on a similar topic can be found here: https://ia600603.us.archive.org/7/items/useofdiispropyle00davi/useofdiispropyle00davi.pdf
